# How to use formula in netsuite saved search

Tags: search, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, kpi

I want to create Custom KPI saved search for Dashboard view.
Custom field 'KPI Account Group' created to classify accounts into groups for KPI formulas
Custom List: KPI Account Group
Values: Expenses, Other Expenses, Interest Expense, Adjustments, Depreciation, Revenue, Other Income, Interest Earned, Fixed Asset

Now I want to calculate following in saved search and show in custom KPI

Custom KPI Formulas-->
Gross Burn: Expenses + Other Expenses + Interest Expense + Adjustments + (Fixed Assets – Depreciation)

Net Burn: Gross Burn – Revenue – Interest Earned – Other Income

EBITDA: Depreciation + Interest Expense + income

Please help! Thanks in advance.

I am using formula in saved search like this but its giving invalid
expression error
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Expenses’ THEN {balance}+
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Interest Expense’ THEN {balance}+
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Adjustments’ THEN {balance}+
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Depreciation’ THEN {balance}+
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Revenue’ THEN {balance}+
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Other Income’ THEN {balance}+
(CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Interest Earned’ THEN {balance}-
CASE WHEN {custrecord1} = ‘Fixed Asset’ THEN {balance}) ELSE 0
END

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the right format for a [CASE statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N2833020.html#bridgehead_N2839038). It's hard to know exactly what formula you need without seeing the rest of your Search, but it looks like several `custrecord1` values should map to positive `balance` while `Interest Earned` should map to negative `balance`.

A `CASE` statement for that looks more like:

```
CASE {custrecord1}
  WHEN 'Expenses' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Interest Expense' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Adjustments' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Depreciation' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Revenue' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Other Income' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Fixed Asset' THEN {balance}
  WHEN 'Interest Earned' THEN -1 * {balance}
ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Please check the requirement above. I am grouping KPI Account Group and doing sum of balances in my search.. I want to use this calculation, Gross Burn= Expenses + Other Expenses + Interest Expense + Adjustments + (Fixed Assets – Depreciation)
Search Columns are,
KPI Account Group     Sum of Balance
Adjustments 61.23
Depreciation 1,825,648.95
Expenses 24,174,440.98
Fixed Asset 4,528,833.45
Interest Earned (125,801.68)
Interest Expense 0.00
Other Expenses 2,861,241.00
Other Income (7,344.56)
Revenue (13,995,902.59)